# Writing C Header files

Tags: c, static-libraries, header-files

I have written a few C programs as part of my college assignments. In case of large programs, I would distribute my code in various files, that I would include as headers in the main C file.
I want to redistribute my code to my friends, but don't want them to be able to access the complete code and plagiarize my program.
So, How can I create statically (or dynamically) linked header files (using *.so or something) to hide the code that I have in the header files?

And if it matters, I am using Linux.

Thanks. :)

Comment: If you don't trust your friends, best to not give them any code at all.

Comment: just share the executable :D

Comment: Your question is not about "writing header files", it's about creating libraries (either .a or .so, since you're on Linux and presumably using gcc). Google how to create a library with gcc and I'm sure you'll find all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `.c` and a `.h` file you can compile them like this to get a shared object file (`.so`) in linux under `gcc`.

`gcc -c -fpic file.c`

`-fpic` is there to ensure that the compiler produces position independent code.

and then to make it shared, just do:

`gcc -shared -o sharedfile.so file.o`

To link against it then use:

`gcc -L<path_to_library> -o testfile main.c -lsharedfile`

`-L<path_to_library>` is used to the the linker where to find our shared object, and `-lsharedfile` is telling it which object to link against.